# froala editor 3 with react js - how to hide toolbar on initialize?

Tags: reactjs, froala

I am trying to implement froala editor in my react js application, and the i need to keep toolbar hidden by default and should only show up when the textarea/editor has focus. in the previous versions the initialize would work like below but not in version 3 anymore. any help is appreciated.

```
'froalaEditor.initialized': function (e, editor) {
editor.toolbar.hide();
}
```

Comment: Did you try my answer below to see if it's working for you?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `config` prop and then set an [`initialized`](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events/#initialized) event like this:

```jsx
(
  <FroalaEditor
    tag='textarea'
    config={{
      events: {
        'initialized': function() {
          // this is the editor instance.
          this.toolbar.hide();
        }
      }
    }}
  />
)
```